# using .when and .done to wait for ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, callback

I building a function that takes user input to process an ajax request, when the ajax is completed, the data stored in a global variable and I can use it for other functions such as graphing.

The problem is my the code would not wait for the ajax to complete before proceeding, and other functions continues with a null variable.

I have tried async:false and used .when and .done but still have no luck. Been working on this for a long time and still not sure what I am missing.
Here is my code:

```
var dbData1 = {};

function renderDs(dsid, refYear) {
  $.ajax({
    data: {
      async: false,
      dsid: dsid,
      refYear: refYear,
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "/data_set_dict",
    beforeSend: function () {
      $("#loading").show();
    },
    complete: function () {
      $("#loading").hide();
    },
    success: function (data){
      console.log(data); //Prints correct data here
      dbData1 = data;
    }
  })
}

renderDs(dsid_value, refYear);
console.log(dbData1); //Prints undefined
```

My attempt using .when also fails

```
$.when(renderDs(dsid_value, refYear)).done(function(data1){
      console.log(data1); //Prints undefined
    });
```

Comment: It needs to be `return $.ajax(...)`

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I also search this question.. And, unfortunately, I didn't find anything.
In my case it was simple functions like "hidePopup()" without any input parametrs
So my solution was like this:

```js
let dbData1 = {};

function renderDs(dsid, refYear) {
  $.ajax({
    data: {
      async: false,
      dsid: dsid,
      refYear: refYear,
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "/data_set_dict",
    beforeSend: function () {
      $("#loading").show();
    },
    complete: function () {
      $("#loading").hide();
    },
    success: function (data){
      customLogFunction(data);
    }
  })
}

function customLogFunction(data) {
   console.log(data);
}

renderDs(dsid_value, refYear);
```

But, are you sure that `async: false` should be inside the `data` block?
Just checked https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ page, "async" property..

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done().

Also try this:

```js
var dbData1 = {};

function renderDs(dsid, refYear) {
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    data: {
      async: false,
      dsid: dsid,
      refYear: refYear,
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "/data_set_dict",
    beforeSend: function () {
      $("#loading").show();
    },
    complete: function () {
      $("#loading").hide();
    },
    success: function (data){
      console.log(data); 
      dbData1 = data;
    }
  })
}

renderDs(dsid_value, refYear);

console.log(dbData1);
```

I have just tried that snippet on my project and it works!
Also check if `post` to the `/data_set_dict` returns data. Simple - but maybe)

Comment: And you can use 

`$.ajax({ // send post}).done(function(data){ // your callback here
})`
construction, that is what mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you have was my initial approach, and I have used the .done with the ajax call. However, I would like to have the callback .done somewhere else. since I have a function that requires 2 ajax response like this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able find a workaround with a video from Pretty Printed on Youtube.
Basically I made the retrieval function a Promise and use .done in other areas I want to use the retrieved data.

```
var globalData = {};
function getData(dsid, refYear) {
  return $.ajax({
    data: {
      async: false,
      dsid: dsid,
      refYear: refYear,
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "/data_set_dict",
    beforeSend: function () {
      $("#loading").show();
    },
    complete: function () {
      $("#loading").hide();
    },
  })
}

var data = getData(dsid_value, refYear);
      data.done(function(data){
        globalData = data;
      });
```